Is it possible to add spl_token_2022 program to ProgramTest in solana_program_test?
I want to write integration test for the transfer hook program by not calling the program directly, but calling spl_token_2022 program (with configured transfer hook) that will trigger transfer hook execution.
At first, I'm trying to create the new ProgramTest with spl_token_2022 like this:
ProgramTest::new(
  "spl_token_2022", 
  spl_token_2022::id(),
  processor!(spl_token_2022::processor::Processor::process))
  ).start_with_context().await

But getting this error
Program file data not available for spl_token_2022

Then I found that the program name should be the name of the file in the target/deploy/ folder of the project, which means that I should deploy spl_token_2022 first.
But is it possible to do it without deploying of the token-2022 myself?

You have two options:

token-2022 is provided by default in solana-program-test, so you don't need to do anything!
if you do want to use some other version of spl_token_2022::processor..., then you can set program_test.prefer_bpf(false) before adding it. This way, program-test won't look for a built BPF program, and will simply use the provided processor function as a fake "native" program. Just be sure to include your program as BPF first.


Thank you!
Adding a bit more context: I've initially tried to create ProgramTest from spl_token_2022 and then add my transfer hook program and got this error. But the right way is to supply my transfer hook program to ProgramTest::new and then either add spl_token_2022 or do nothing.
